# HTML/PHP/JQUERY - "alert" names of multiple <select> on change

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Using PHP, I retrieve several data lines from a MySQL database into a HTML table.
At the end of each line, I added a "select" element that shows a property that a user can modify.
If someone selects another property (via one of the "select") than the one that is stored in the database, I want to update this line/field inside the database.

Below, one of the "select" element:

```
<select class="browser-default" id="FKPRIORITYUSER" name="FKPRIORITYUSER486">
  <option value="99">TBD</option>
  <option value="1">Critical</option>
  <option value="2">High</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Low</option>
</select>
```

All those "select" elements are the same, except that their "name" is different : FKPRIORITYUSER486, FKPRIORITYUSER487, etc.

To detect the change of value via the select, I'm using a simple jQuery function. For now, I'm just trying to "alert" the name of the "select" component which triggered this function:

```
var $select2 = $('select.browser-default');

$select2.on('change', function (e) {
  alert ( $('select').attr('name') );
  alert( e.target.value );
});
```

But, the problem is that this alert() function only returns the name "FKPRIORITYUSER486"...
It's ok if I click on the corresponding "select", but fails when I'm changing a value of the "select" named FKPRIORITYUSER487 :)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good structure for your form.

Comment: Hi Grumpy! Can you explain? Now i have several "select" with different names and ids, but the problem is still the same

Comment: Why do you have so many `select` elements with almost identical names?

Comment: One select for each line retrieved from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the ID of an element is supposed to be unique. You do not really need an ID here but incase you do, do the same as what you did with Name attribute (use the same value).

Now the code to get the name of the select that is changed. You are calling the function on change of any select but alerting the name of first select by hard coding `$('select')`. You need to use `$(this)` reference to refer to THE select that was changed, like this:

```
var $select2 = $('select.browser-default');

$select2.on('change', function (e) {
  alert ( $(this).attr('name') );  
});
```

This is the fix to the issue at hand. The best way to do what you want to do is assign data-id to each select. like this:

```
<select class="browser-default" data-id="486" name="FKPRIORITYUSER486">
```

and then read the id like this

```
var changedId = $(this).data('id');
```

and get the selected/changed value like this

```
var changedValue = $(this).val();
```

and then pass the data to your server side script/code to update database by sending id and changed value.

Comment: Hello Nawed Khan, thank you so much for your answer, this works like a charm...

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it did. You can now approve the answer :)

Comment: Done!  Thanks again, and HNY ;)